# Testing Spring Controller with @Autowired fields, returns null for fields but gets the controller

Tags: java, dependency-injection, spring-test-mvc

Hi I have a controller that I am trying to test, without mocking.

```
@Controller
public class MyController
{
    @Autowired
    private Type1 service1;

    @Autowired
    private Type2 service2;

    ....
}
```

Test Class:

```
public class testController
{
    @Autowired
    private MyController controller;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        //setupStuff

    }

    @Test
    public void testControllerMethod()
    {
        //Test method
    }

}
```

When debugging through the test, I get the value for controller but the value for autowired service1 and 2 are null.

The xml file does have base packages for all the services and controller in `<context: component-scan>`

Which if removed gives me error creating bean. Even if i remove one of the service base packages.

Is there anything test specific I need to add to my configuration?

Type1:

```
public interface Type1
{
    String method1();
    String method2();
}
```

Type1 implementing class that is autowired is:

```
@Service
public class Type1Class implements Type1
{
    @Autowired
    private Type3 service3;

    //Methods implementatoin of Type1
}



Type2 is similar to this.
```

Comment: Show us your config. For instances to be `@Autowired`, beans need to be declared or scanned for.

Comment: Show the source for `Type1` and `Type2`.

Comment: I have the base package added to context:component-scanbase-package="package for controller, package for type1,.. etc".
Do I need to add to this?

Comment: I will add the mock of source as edit to the question.

Comment: Have you annotated `Type1` and `Type2` with `@Service`?

Comment: Yes the Type1 and Type2 Implmentations have @Service.